# Can I apply a coupon to a one time charge using Laravel Cachier (Stripe provider)?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments

I have seen in the laravel docs that coupons can be applied to subscriptions.

```
$user->newSubscription('main', 'monthly')
     ->withCoupon('code')
     ->create($creditCardToken);
```

What I wanted to know, is - can coupons be applied to one time charges?

```
$user->charge(100);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coupons can't be applied to one-time charges. They only apply to invoices which are associated with subscriptions.

You'll need to calculate the amount to charge based on the discount you want to apply and build your own coupon system. Stripe has a recipe for this [here](https://stripe.com/docs/recipes/coupons-for-charges).